# How to display only one text box at a time and click to next display next input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three fields and one next button. I have to display each field one by one after clicking on next button. Means I have to display only one field at a time.
For example. First text box displaying with next button after clicked on next button then display a second text box with next button same on third one but this time no next button. It will display submit button. Would you help me out in this?

```css
.steps{
  max-width:500px;
  height:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:70px 0;
  background:#ffffff;
  border:1px solid #e1e8f2;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
label
{ 
  display: block;
}
.field-set
{
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="steps">
  <p class="form_title">Please Fill The field Bellow</p>
  <form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="field-set">
    <label>name</label>
      <input type="text"  id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter You Name"/>      
    </div>

      <div  class="field-set">
      <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter You Email"/> 
      </div>

      <div  class="field-set">
      <label>mobile</label>
        <input type="text"  id="mob" name="mob" placeholder="Enter Your mobile no"/> 
      </div>

      <div  class="field-set">
        <input type="submit" name="next" value="next" id="click_next"> 
      </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
var count = $(".field-set").length - 1;
var countshow = 1;
$("#click_next").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(".field-set").eq((countshow - 1)).hide();
  if (count > countshow) {
    $(".field-set").eq(countshow).show();
    countshow++;
  } else {
    $("form").unbind("submit").submit();
  }
})
```

I've also changed some of your css.

```
.field-set {
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}

.field-set:first-of-type,
.field-set:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
var count = $(".field-set").length - 1;
var countshow = 1;
$("#click_next").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $(".field-set").eq((countshow - 1)).hide();
  if (count > countshow) {
    $(".field-set").eq(countshow).show();
    if ((count - 1) == countshow) {$(this).val("sumbit")}
  } else {
    $("form").unbind("submit").submit();
  }
  countshow++;

})
```

```css
.steps {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 70px 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #e1e8f2;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

label {
  display: block;
}

.field-set {
  text-align: left;
  display: none;
}

.field-set:first-of-type,
.field-set:last-of-type {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  start Form Steps  -->
<div class="steps">
  <p class="form_title">Please Fill The field Bellow</p>
  <form action="#" method="post" autocomplete="off">

    <div class="field-set">
      <label>name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter You Name" />
    </div>

    <div class="field-set">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter You Email" />
    </div>

    <div class="field-set">
      <label>mobile</label>
      <input type="text" id="mob" name="mob" placeholder="Enter Your mobile no" />
    </div>

    <div class="field-set">
      <input type="submit" name="next" value="next" id="click_next">
    </div>

  </form>


</div>
<!--  End Form Steps  -->
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Carsten, After clicked on next button I have to hide the previous field. I have to display only one field at a time.

Comment: @NarendraVerma Updated

Comment: Thanks again for helping me. My 85% issue got resolved. now can you help me to set at the end submit button instead of on Next button?

Comment: @NarendraVerma Like this? else im not sure i understand

Comment: Almost close but it is displaying after the third field when clicked. I have to display on third. I mean First field next button-> second field next button-> the third field submits button. like this.

Comment: What happens Mr.Carsten, Any help in this?

Comment: @NarendraVerma First of all, i have other things to do, I spend about 30 min helping you, and Second, this site is not a Coding service.

Comment: I am so sorry for that. I was getting an issue that's why I contact you. Upvote from my side for helping me a lot.

Comment: @NarendraVerma please accept this answer instead of mine to accept best answer

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var step = 1;
  $('#btn').click(function(){
    if( step < 5 )
    {
      $('.txt').eq(step - 1).hide();
      $('.txt').eq(step).show();
      step++;
    }
    else
    { /*Submit the form here*/ }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="txt" placeholder="1">
<input class="txt" style="display:none;" placeholder="2">
<input class="txt" style="display:none;" placeholder="3"><input class="txt" style="display:none;" placeholder="4">
<input class="txt" style="display:none;" placeholder="5">

<input type="button" value="Next" id="btn">
```

Comment: Mr.Mayank at the end instated of NEXT button I need Submit. can you help me in this?

Comment: Put a check on step count, and after count reaches the limit submit the form

Comment: Commenting mistake, please check the answer now